# How to select an option from the view and search in the controller? (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a code on my blade template page with a search field and a select with options.
The user types what he wants to search in the search field and selects a search option, which must be sent to the controller to search and return the searched customers according to the selected search option.
The view part is ready, but I am still unable to find a way for the controller to choose this option and do the research accordingly.

My client view page:

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="POST" class="form form-inline" role="search">
          @csrf
          <label class="procurar">Procurar for:</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <label>Filtro:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select name="busca" class="form-control">
              <option value="nome">Nome</option>
              <option value="tipo_pessoa">Tipo de Pessoa</option>
              <option value="cidade">Cidade</option>
              <option value="uf">Estado</option>
              <option value="cpf_cnpj">CPF /CNPJ</option>
              <option value="tipo_cliente">Tipo de Cliente</option>
              <option value="onde_nos_encontrou">Onde nos encontrou</option>
           </select>
          </div>
        </form>
```

My search function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
   {
       if ($request->nome)
        {
                $nome = $request->nome;
                $clients = Client::where('nome', 'like', '%'.$nome.'%')
                    ->orderBy('nome')
                    ->paginate(8);

                return view('clients.index')
                ->with('clients', $clients);
            }
            if ($request->uf)
            {
                $uf = $request->uf;
                $clients = Client::where('uf', 'like', '%'.$uf.'%')
                    ->orderBy('uf')
                    ->paginate(8);

                return view('clients.index')
                ->with('clients', $clients);
            }
            return redirect()->route('clients.index');
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of `busca` as that's a select's name. The selected value will be there.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $busca = $request->input('busca', 'nome');

    $clients = Client::where($busca, 'like', '%' . $busca . '%')
                     ->orderBy($busca)
                     ->paginate(8);

    return view('clients.index')
        ->with('clients', $clients);
}
```